# Weather forecast using external API

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, weather-api

I am trying to get weather forecast using external API of `openweathermap.org`, and want to use angular.js so far i am able to get forecast of single city without using `API KEY` and trying to get forecast of multiple cities with help of API Key as i am not able to find the proper way to do it with api key

So here is clear picture of what i am trying to do

1.The app should accept multiple city names from the user 
2. Based on the city names entered, the app should show the the weather forecast for the 14 days for each city

```
var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', []);

var apiKey = '89b59e4d7d07894243b5acd24e7f18a3';
artistControllers.controller('WController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
console.log('ijij');
$http.jsonp('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id=524901').success(function(err,data){
if(err){
  console.log(err);
}
$scope.data=data;
console.log(data);
});
}]);
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation is says:

> **How to use API key**
>
> Add the following parameter to the GET request:
>   `APPID=APIKEY`
>   Example:
>   `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID=1111111111`
>
> OR add the following line to http header of request to the server:
>   `x-api-key:APIKEY`

So you should be fine by appending the API key behind the url in your $http call.

See: http://openweathermap.org/appid

OR, as the documentation says, you can add an extra header in your HTTP request. You can do that in AngularJS like so:

```
var req = {
 method: 'GET',
 url: 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id=524901',
 headers: {
   'x-api-key': '89b59e4d7d07894243b5acd24e7f18a3'
 }
}

$http(req).success(function(){...}).error(function(){...});
```

Link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: thanks for answer but when i did `console.log` it shows empty string or null, can you please provide an example where i can attach api key behind url as the way i am doing it is not working either.

Comment: @davidwarne : OK - what is the method you are trying to call. I cannot find the method for bulk weather forecast.

Comment: @spike-thats what i want to know, so that with the help of this API, i can create a method to call bulk forecast.

Comment: @davidwarne how about this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln758jas/1/. I implemented the API as an AngularJS service. You can just loop through your cities and get the weather for them.

Comment: @spike-what if i want to give multiple cities name in input?

Comment: @spike-as per solution you didn't use API Key and still getting city forecast so what's the use of api key?

Comment: @davidwarne - For multiple names, you could split by comma or something ( http://jsfiddle.net/Ln758jas/3/ ) but this is just plain JS development - you need to be able to do that yourself. Indeed, I'm not using the key. The examples didn't need it. Try without and as soon as you get a non 200 - you know you're going to have to start using the key.